# Why do my service is still listed after app uninstall?

Tags: android, service

I have updated an app that run one service, but after that update I had two services running in the phone service list.

The service still persist after app uninstall.

I though they could only be one instance of an android service.

Do you guys know what might cause this ?

My phone is old (Android 5.0.1).

Answer (score 0):

The service continues to run because on app update or uninstall the onDestroy method is not called. This happens when the application is still running and it is being forced stopped by the system in order to proceed to uninstall or update.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onDestroy()

Also, when an application package is beeing removed:

> The package that is being removed does not receive this Intent.

(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED)